# My bash script isn't sending messages to my slack channel

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, webhooks, slack

I have a bash script that's supposed to send a message to a Slack channel when a GCP VM is running outside of appropriate time.

I found a script on Github that does a similar job but I modified it to fit my need but for some reason it's not sending the message needed.

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

hour=$(date +%H)
script_dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
if [[ $hour -gt 17 || $hour -lt 9 ]] ; then
    HOST=$(hostname)
    message="${HOST} is still running. Please make sure to shut it down"
    # Read the webhook URL from the slack-hook file.
    hook=$(cat "${script_dir}/slack-hook")

    # Send a POST HTTP request to the Slack webhook.
    curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"text\": \"${message}\"}" "${hook}"
fi
```

The `slack-hook` file contains the url for the slack webhook that receives incoming messages.